# Using CodeCompare with git from WSL

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, codecompare

I really like Devart's CodeCompare and its excellent integration with Visual Studio. However, these days I do development in VSCode under WSL2. VSCode has a pretty decent diff and merge tool but it cannot be compared to CodeCompare (no pun intended). I really want to use CodeCompare from VSCode (Devart please look into it - this is the most popular dev.environment these days) or just from the good ole Linux git CLI.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. If someone has a better suggestion (this one is a little slow), please share it.
So, I added these lines to my ~/.gitconfig:

```
[diff]
    tool = codecompare
    guitool = codecompare

[difftool "codecompare"]
    cmd = \"${ProgramFilesW64}/Devart/Code Compare/CodeCompare.exe\" /SC=git /ENVIRONMENT=standalone /W /T1="ours" /T2="theirs" \"$(wslpath -w $LOCAL)\" \"$(wslpath -w $REMOTE)\"
    renames = true

[merge]
    tool = codecompare
    guitool = codecompare

[mergetool "codecompare"]
    cmd = \"${ProgramFilesW64}/Devart/Code Compare/CodeMerge.exe\" /SC=git /ENVIRONMENT=standalone /MF=\"`wslpath -m $LOCAL`\" /TF=\"`wslpath -m $REMOTE`\" /BF=\"`wslpath -m $BASE`\" /RF=\"`wslpath -m $MERGED`\" /MT="ours-HEAD" /TT="theirs" /RT="result" /BT="base"
    trustExitCode = true

[mergetool]
    keepBackup = false
```

Comment: In your setup, the CodeCompare's path may be different, e.g. 
`/mnt/c/Program Files/Devart/Code Compare/codecompare.exe`